# A few questions about MobaXterm passwords?

Tags: windows-10, security, remote-desktop, passwords, mobaxterm

everyone. I bought MobaXterm this year but just now trying to figure out all the features it has.
I came to the security and passwords and have a few questions:

1. Is it possible to use only Master Password to reveal Passwords? (currently MobaXterm also offers to use Windows Account password and I would like to disable this option). I want to access my passwords only via Master Password, since Windows Password is not as strong as Master Password.
2. Is it possible to add 2FA in order to open MobaXterm? So, I would use Master Password to login and after that I would need to enter 2FA as well to open a program?
3. Let's say someone got access to my laptop where MobaXterm is open. Is it possible to have a hidden folder or secured folder with my servers? In this case even MobaXterm is open, they would still need to know the password to my hidden/secured folder in order to access all the servers? In current state it means that MobaXterm has access to all my servers without any extra layers of security (for example my saved RDP connections can be open the moment MobaXterm is open).
4. My passwords are stored as a "registry user" option. Is it possible that someone could reveal my passwords if they have access to my registry but they don't know my Master Password? I understand they can reveal it if I store it as ini file, but what if it's "registry user" option? https://github.com/HyperSine/how-does-MobaXterm-encrypt-password
5. Does MobaXterm team have any files of my account stored online? or everything is stored locally and only my license is stored online for verification purposes?

I am trying to learn more about how I can securely use MobaXtrem and what measures I should take in order to keep my security level high.

I appreciate your responses and suggestions!

Comment: The author of this program is AWESOME (especially to paying customers).  Super nice.  Have you asked *him* these questions?  I am not dodging these questions but nobody can answer it better than the author and by buying a license, you get support for questions like these.

Comment: Thank you. Found the support email and sent them a message as well. Also, would love to hear a feedback from people who is using the program as well, and how they setup their security settings. Will wait for the response from the team and will update my ticket as well when I hear from them.

Comment: @euGenius, hello! Did you receive a response to your message?